# Asciidoc: How do I preserve both spacing and formatting

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I need to produce the following output in asciidoc format, exactly as shown, including the spacing (it's VERY important that the columns line up), the font colouring and formatting and highlighting, and keep the asterisks at the start of the line.

[image: target asciidoc output]

As a code block, I can get the spacing OK, keep all the special characters, but loose all the formatting. And the formatting is as important as the text, if not here precisely, but in many other places. No sense in having copy referring to the highlighted element in a block of text that is not capable of showing highlighting.

```
aciextrtr# show ip bgp vrf BGP-FXX
...<output omitted>...
   Network          Next Hop            Metric  LocPrf   Weight Path
*>l1.F.0.XX/32      0.0.0.0                        100    32768 i
*>l10.FXX.3.0/24    0.0.0.0                        100    32768 i
*>l10.FXX.20.0/24   0.0.0.0                        100    32768 i
```

Curiously, the BEST I've been able to discover is the [verse] block , but it has ridiculously wide spacing between lines, and I had to escape a few special characters (* and the ellipses).

[image: rendered using [verse]]

As a kludge, perhaps there is a way of re-defining [verse] so that it doesn't leave huge gaps between lines, but hopefully there is a way defining my own model based on verse that does what I want.

Curiously, Visual Studio code renders it more accurately than https://asciidoclive.com/edit/scratch/1 - I'd paste the source here but of course it won't render properly in this environment (strips back-ticks etc)

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [literal block](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/verbatim/listing-blocks/) to specify a monospace font and keep the lines together. Use the [`subs` attribute](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/subs/apply-subs-to-blocks/) to re-enable inline formatting.

For example:

```
[subs="+quotes"]
----
... <ellipses are not substituted> ... 
*>l1.[.red]##F##.0.XX/32      #0.0.0.0#                        100    32768
----
```

Comment: [subs=normal] is certainly better than [verse] - I still have to escape the three periods to prevent them being converted to ellipses (I can live with that). Perhaps I should ask a new question about any flags that can be set to prevent this, but if anyone comments to let me know I'd be grateful.

Comment: Ahh @Richard-Smith. You've given me a choice between the Devil and the Deep Blue Sea! - I tried `subs=quotes`  but now I have to escape `<` characters.  Most of the blocks I want have (as my example shows) have the sequence `...<output omitted>...` included. So honestly - your answer when it said [subs=normal] was much better. I suggest you edit it back to the original, unless you have a better alternative that copes with both `...` and `<`

Comment: After further experimentation, it seems you want to use a plus sign in front of "quotes". This is probably because the *literal block* already does most of the work, and we only need to *add* the "quotes" substitution step.